# "Slicing" dictionary keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary

In python I can use slice objects like this:

```
a = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")
x = slice(2)
print(a[x])
```

I need to do something similar with dictionary keys, for example:

```
output = {
    'track': {
        'urlparams': {
            'trackartist': 'artist_name'
        }
    }
}
key = dict_key_slice("['track']['urlparams']['trackartist']")
print(ouput[key])
```

Instead of typing out:

```
output = {
    'track': {
        'urlparams': {
            'trackartist': 'artist_name'
        }
    }
}
print(
\toutput['track']['urlparams']['trackartist']
)
```

Need to mention I do understand that it won't be a slice as it is, but the idea is that object needs to be reusable. I guess it will probably help me with keeping DRY principle in code.

Tried creating my own class that implements given functionality. I couldn't make it usable with the mentioned syntax

Comment: Your examples do not make any sense. Especially outputs. We surmise (not that easily) that you have a dictionary, and want to extract a subdictionary. But that is really not very clear. Please include minimal reproducible example, without ellipsis, with sample data, of what is the input, and what is (in python syntax) the expected output.

Comment: Edited, could you recheck

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a python function, but you can create your own.

```
from functools import reduce
def dict_key_slice(nested_dict, path, split_by=":"):
    return reduce(lambda d, n: d[n], path.split(split_by), nested_dict)
```

given your dict as:

```
output = {
    'track': {
        'urlparams': {
            'trackartist': 'artist_name'
        }
    }
}

print(dict_key_slice(output, "track"))
>>> {'urlparams': {'trackartist': 'artist_name'}}

print(dict_key_slice(output, "track:urlparams"))
>>> {'trackartist': 'artist_name'}
```